# VS Code IntelliSense for variables in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am a little bit new to python in Visual Studio Code. I was wondering how IntelliSense works for variables in python.

If I have:

`var1 = "abc"`

Then if I type var1.xxx I will get a lot of IntelliSense suggestions such as .split. .replace and many more.

but if i do

```
var1 = input()
```

Then this would also be considered a string, but now if I type var1.xxx I get no IntelliSense at all. In, for example, pycharm I would still get a lot of IntelliSense functions here also.

Are my VS Code settings not correct, or is this simply the way VS Code works?

Comment: Have a look at these two links https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

Comment: I checked through the documentation and there seemed to be no mention about this specific topic :(

Comment: Most python versions don't have type hints (added in Python 3.7.?) so the intellisense does not know the type of the returned value of functions. If you use literals or maybe even `list(), dict(),...` then it knows the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are at least using the Microsoft language server 0.3.59.0 (beta) then you will get the expected IntelliSense:
[image]

Comment: Oh thats exactly what i was looking for.
For those who wonders how to implement it, Go into json settings in vscode and type "python.jediEnabled": false, and simply reload the editor. Awesome!